# Where is Napoleon during the battle of the cowshed?

Tags: george-orwell, animal-farm

In *Animal Farm*, where is Napoleon during the battle of the cowshed? Is this significant? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is there any connection between the two questions you're asking here? In general, one should avoid asking more than one thing in the same question post, unless they're strongly related like subqueries of the same question. If this isn't the case here, maybe consider splitting this post into two separate questions?

Comment: Sure, I'm new, so sorry.

Comment: No problem. I've edited this post to focus on only one question; you're welcome to post the second one (about the windmill) as a [new question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

Napoleon is absent during the battle of the Cowshed in Orwell's *Animal Farm*.  Orwell makes a point to show that though nobody spoke more fiercely about the danger of the humans and their imminent threat of reappearing on the farm, when it came to actually going to war with them, Napoleon left the fighting to the other animals. His political opponent, Snowball, led the charge against the humans and got wounded in the process, earning him great honour/prestige among the animals.  This is another example of Napoleon's hypocritical stance on the farm. He wants all the rewards with no sacrifice.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! (Take our [tour], it gets you a shiny badge) This looks good; it would be a better answer if you [edit] in some supporting quotes from the novel.